# How to render elements with if conditions in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I have a profile page for users , each user has a rate from 0 to 5.
I want to fill the stars based on the user's rank.
e.g. if user's rate is 4 I need 4 stars to be filled and 1 star be blank

here is my code in render method:

```
<Text>{item.rate}</Text> // here I get the rate from api 0 to 5
<View>
    <Icon name="star" color="#9fa1a7" type="solid" size={16}/>
    <Icon name="star" color="#9fa1a7" type="solid" size={16}/>
    <Icon name="star" color="#9fa1a7" type="solid" size={16}/>
    <Icon name="star" color="#9fa1a7" type="solid" size={16}/>
    <Icon name="star" color="#ffffff" type="solid" size={16}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your number of stars does not change, but only their colors, use `color={item.rate >= X ? 'color on' : 'color off'}` on each Icon:

```
<Text>{item.rate}</Text>
<View>
    <Icon name="star" color={item.rate >= 1 ? '#9fa1a7' : '#ffffff'} type="solid" size={16}/>
    <Icon name="star" color={item.rate >= 2 ? '#9fa1a7' : '#ffffff'} type="solid" size={16}/>
    <Icon name="star" color={item.rate >= 3 ? '#9fa1a7' : '#ffffff'} type="solid" size={16}/>
    <Icon name="star" color={item.rate >= 4 ? '#9fa1a7' : '#ffffff'} type="solid" size={16}/>
    <Icon name="star" color={item.rate >= 5 ? '#9fa1a7' : '#ffffff'} type="solid" size={16}/>
</View>
```

Or generate the stars from an array to reduce repetition:

```
<Text>{item.rate}</Text>
<View>{
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(score =>
        <Icon
            name="star"
            color={item.rate >= score ? '#9fa1a7' : '#ffffff'}
            type="solid"
            size={16}
         />
    )
}</View>
```

Comment: Or, in a more elegant way (I think), you can use `[...Array(5)].map(...)` instead of writing the entire array of five elements

Comment: @Milore, good suggestion, however, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is shorter. Also I would use `Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => i)` instead to get a range.

Comment: Yeah, my suggestion is reasonable in a different contest, for example in one with more elements to render

Comment: @Milore, absolutely, but you will only get an array of `undefined` values though

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** this answers "how to to conditionally render a component" (i.e. the title of the question) but an approach that changes the star color will better solve OPs problem.

---

You can conditionally render a component as below:

```
<View>
  {condition && <Component />}
</View>
```

Here you want to render each star covered by rate, so you are looking for something like this:

```
<View>
  {item.rate > 0 && <Icon name="star" color="#9fa1a7" type="solid" size={16}/>}
  {item.rate > 1 && <Icon name="star" color="#9fa1a7" type="solid" size={16}/>}
  {item.rate > 2 && <Icon name="star" color="#9fa1a7" type="solid" size={16}/>}
  {/* etc. */}
</View>
```

Comment: The number of stars does not change, only their colors

Comment: @jo_va true, and your answer solves OPs problem better (hence my upvote).  However, the question does ask how to conditionally render components so I decided to leave this here as it answers that aspect.

Comment: You are right, the question is not so clear, this is valid solution, +1

Answer (score -1):

```
const itemarry=new Array().fill(item.rate);
 render(){
 <Text>{item.rate}</Text> // here I get the rate from api 0 to 5
  <View>
    {itemarry.map((item,index),()=>
    <Icon name="star" color="#9fa1a7" type="solid" size={16} />
    )}
  </View>
```

}

Comment: How could that work, each star will have the same color

Comment: I thought he is asking about the print star only . no grey color stars .   if the rating is 3 then it will print 3 stars .